Setting up Gitlab CI/CD for R packages
This Gitlab CI/CD pipeline works fine for me (build after this blogpost):
image: rocker/r2u
stages:
    - build

buildbinary:
  stage: build
  script:
    #- apt-get update
    #- apt-get install -y
    - install.r remotes
    - R -e "remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - '*.Rcheck/'

However, it installs the remotes package and the packages from the DESCRIPTION file on every run. The blog post mentioned above shows some caching mechanism from Gitlab. It redefines the library path to installed_deps. The YAML now looks like this:
image: rocker/r2u
stages:
    - build
    
default:
before_script:
     # this allows gitlab to cache the installed packages from install_deps(), see section "cache" below
    - mkdir -p installed_deps
    - echo 'R_LIBS="installed_deps"' > .Renviron
    - echo 'R_LIBS_USER="installed_deps"' >> .Renviron
    - echo 'R_LIBS_SITE="installed_deps"' >> .Renviron

buildbinary:
  stage: build
  script:
    #- apt-get update
    #- apt-get install -y
    - install.r remotes
    - R -e "remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - installed_deps/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - '*.Rcheck/'
  only:
    - main
    - dev

This pipeline fails with the error message "Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘bspm’". The package bpsm is not directly mentioned in the YAML file. I believe it used by install.r when it installs remotes. I tried to install bpsm both via install.r and R -e "install.packages but without success. The error message here is: the package does not exist for this version of R.
Any hints how to resolve this are very appreciated.

It is bspm, not bpsm, and available on CRAN.

Aside: stop using ‘remotes’, it’s obsolete. ‘pak’ is its modern replacement and it is superior in every regard.

Just for reference, I ended up defining my own image for CI purposes:
FROM rocker/r2u

# install needed packages
RUN install2.r --error remotes lintr covr

and then use this image in my .gitlab-ci.yml:
image: gitlab.myhose.com/docker/r-ci # the image defined above
stages:
  - build
  - check

buildbinary:
  stage: build
  script:
    - R -e "remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"
    - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
    - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
    - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - '*.Rcheck/'
  only:
    - main
    - dev

No need for caching inside the .gitlab-ci.yml.
